Space Complexity of Storing a Binary Representation of an Integer
If I have an algorithm that simply converts an input integer to its binary representation and stores the result, what is the space complexity of this algorithm?
I initially assumed that the space required would be proportional to the number of bits in the binary representation of the number. This would give an O(logn) space complexity, since the number of bits required to represent an integer n in binary is roughly log(2)n.
However, I’ve recently considered the fact that the input would be constrained to a fixed range, such as 2^31 - 1 for a 32-bit signed integer. In this case, the length of the binary representation is capped at a fixed length of 32 bits, regardless of the input size, since the input integer is constrained to fit within 32 bits.
So, is it correct to conclude that the space complexity of storing the binary representation of the integer is thus constant / O(1), given the fixed upper bound on the length of the binary string?

It depends on whether you support arbitrary-precision arithmetic or not.

@dan04, when the OP wrote that "input would be constrained to a fixed range, such as ... a 32-bit signed integer", that choice is already made (to my understanding).

"simply converts an input integer to its binary representation" <<< How is the input integer represented in the input, if not in binary??

Also, when talking about space complexity or time complexity of an algorithm, it is typical to express it as a function of the size of the input. If the input is the representation of an integer K in a base b, then its size n is already n = log_b(K). So the algorithm would take O(n) = O(log(K)) space, not O(log(n)) space.

Thanks for the replies. I was going to provide an edit but decided to add my own answer. There seems to be a few different ideas and opinions here, and after looking into this question further, I've realized that the core of the discussion revolves around how we define the scope of our analysis—what we care about when we talk about algorithmic complexity. Does the underlying representation of the input matter in our analysis, or should we only focus on the abstract, logical behavior of the algorithm?
Here’s an adjacent question that helps us explore this idea:
If I have a program that copies an input integer to another variable, this is typically assumed to be a constant space operation. But since the input integer is likely represented as a binary number under the hood, why is this not considered an O(log n) operation, since we are copying all log(n) bits from one variable to another?
One possible answer is that we are dealing with a fixed-size input, such as a 32-bit integer, which would make the operation constant in terms of space because the input is capped at a maximum size (regardless of the actual value of the integer). But is this truly the reason we consider the operation constant space, or does the space complexity analysis depend more on what we measure the complexity with respect to?
The key insight, I believe, is that the answer depends on our model of computation—on what we are willing to count as "space" or "time" in our complexity analysis. Complexity analysis is inherently tied to the assumptions we make about the nature of the input and the environment. As one comment puts it, "All the computations of complexity depend on your model of computation, in other words on what you would like to count." Are we counting only the space that our algorithm explicitly allocates, or are we including the underlying machine representation (e.g., the binary encoding of integers)?
In this context, the RAM model of algorithmic analysis is usually what we are concerned with. In this model, the focus is on high-level operations, such as additions and comparisons, and assumes a fixed-size machine word (e.g., 32 or 64 bits). The time and space complexity are measured based on the number of operations required to solve a problem, ignoring the details of machine word size or arbitrary precision. For most algorithmic problems and competitive programming algorithms, this model is used, as it abstracts away the details of the underlying hardware and focuses on the algorithm’s efficiency with respect to input size.
In short, the real question boils down to what you’re measuring your algorithmic complexity with respect to—the input value itself or the representation of the input value on the machine. If we consider the input value in its raw form, with a fixed bit size (say 32 or 64 bits), then copying it would be an O(1) operation. But if we delve into the details of how the input is represented on the machine (in binary, with a potentially varying bit length), we might argue that the operation could take O(log n) space, reflecting the number of bits involved.
Ultimately, it’s less about whether the input is “arbitrary precision” versus “fixed size” and more about what assumptions we make when measuring algorithmic complexity. These assumptions about the model of computation—what we count and how we count it—determine whether we consider the operation constant space or logarithmic.
In Short: O(1) time with respect to what we are generally concerned about. We can do complexity analysis with respect to other lower-level details, but this generally is outside the scope of our model of analysis.
Note that also assumes that when we store the binary representation of the integer, we are not storing it as a string, as this would definitely require O(logn) space.

Asymptotic complexity analysis assumes that the input can take any large size. Once you put a cap on the input size, the notion of asymptotic complexity does not apply.
When you limit the input to the range of a 32-bit integer, you are right there is also a cap on the space consumption, and so the space complexity is O(1). It couldn't be anything else, as there is no  that could be arbitrary large.

About limitations
There is a difference between a limit that is set explicitly (e.g. the input is a 32-bit integer), and the limits of a specific computer (e.g. it has access to 1 TB of memory).
The first kind of limit does not depend on which computer you decide to run the algorithm on. The 32-bit limit would be part of the input procedure, even if run on a 128-bit word architecture. As this is an explicit limit provided in the problem description, we can even think of an algorithm that would fail if the input violates this constraint, and still consider it correct.
The second kind of limit is generally not specified in the constraints of the problem description. So in case no preset limit is given for "integers" (i.e. they are "big integers"), we understand that the practical limit will depend on the constraints of the computer that runs the algorithm. We can always imagine a (theoretical) computer that would have access to more memory than the current largest supercomputer, even if we take into account that the observable universe is finite. It doesn't even have to be a computer that actually exists. Also, if an actual computer would run into an out-of-memory error, as a consequence of the size of the input, we would not immediately conclude the algorithm is faulty. (Possibly, we would consider the algorithm to be inefficient and try to improve on that).
I would therefore say that if you make the 32-bit limitation part of the problem description, the space complexity is O(1), while if this limit is not part of the problem description, we can do as if there is no memory limit and perform an asymptotic complexity analysis.

The algorithm you are implementing requires O(log n) space.
The implementation limits the input size.  We don't usually talk about the asymptotic complexity of implementations.  It doesn't really apply, since everything in reality is bounded.

What is n? The length of the input?

No, it's the actual number, i.e., ~2^(input_size)... at least this is what I infer from the question.

Then I think it is worth restating what n is in the answer, since this "O(log(n))" is actually linear in the size of the input, and not what we usually call logspace. Also, if the input is already in binary, then "converting to binary" is a no-operation, so arguably the algorithm doesn't take any space at all.

Presumably the input is a decimal string or similar. To read someone's words in "good faith", you have to start with the assumption that what they're saying makes sense, I think.  I think the OP has managed to communicate his question.  I also think I have managed to communicate the answer, which is actually general and does not, in fact, depend on the unstated specifics.

Then you and I disagree about what "good faith" means. I think when someone is expressing their confusion about a topic, "good faith" starts by explaining things in detail including the basics, as opposed to taking everything at the letter and filling in the inevitable blanks by presuming. Whether n is the size of the input, or the value represented by the input, and how is n represented, are vital to this question and not just "unstated specifics" that can be glossed over as if they were obvious.

Understanding that the input to an algorithm is a string that represents a number, rather than just "a number", is at the very heart of this question.
